# How to number format Datatable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I want to number formatting in datatable from client site.
My code is following:

```
$('#mytableid').DataTable( {

    bDestroy: true,
    bPaginate : false,
    bInfo : false,
    searching: gTableSearchEnable,
    aoColumns:[{"title":"Name","className":"dt-left"},{"title":"Amount","className":"dt-right"}],
    data: [["Rubel","1260"],["Nazim","2415"]]
} );
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/formatNumber
 Go through this link.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. And it's working..

```js
aoColumns:[
 { "title":"Name","className":"dt-left" },
 { "title":"Amount","className":"dt-right",
   "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '')
 }
]
```